# Photo albums not showing up on iPhone (syncing with Mac)

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos

After syncing photo albums from a Mac to iPhone (11.3) latest added albums don't show up in the album list on the phone anymore. I use the syncing function in iTunes (12.7.4) with "selected albums" option.

Tapping on "Albums" in the iPhone photo app is showing albums from the past. However, recent selected albums in iTunes don't show up after sync. However, using the search function the albums and photos did sync to phone. I believe this is a bug in the album list feature of the iPhone. I'm running out of ideas. Anyone has a seen this before? Any workaround to fix this? I loose track on my photos :(

PS: For various reasons iCloud syncing doesn't work for me, so I'm looking for a fix to sync locally and also selected albums only